# NSTextAlignment.Justified for UILabel does not work

Tags: swift, uilabel, text-alignment, justify

I am trying to justify my `UILabel` text but it does not work.

Declaration of my `UIView`:

```
descriptionUIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

Declaration of my `UILabel`:

```
bottleDescriptionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: widthMargin, y: bottleDescriptionTitleLabel.frame.maxY + heightMargin, width: self.view.frame.width - (2 * widthMargin), height: heightBottleDescription - (2 * heightMargin)))
bottleDescriptionLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16)
bottleDescriptionLabel.text = bottleDescriptionString
bottleDescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
bottleDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
bottleDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know what else to use that `NSTextAlignment.Justified` to justified my text. Should I use a `UITextView` instead?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to create an NSMutableParagraphStyle in combination with an NSAttributedString in order to display text as justified. 
The important part is to set NSBaselineOffsetAttributedName to 0.0.

Here's an example how to put everything together:

```
let sampleText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: sampleText,
    attributes: [
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
        NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)
    ])

let label = UILabel()
label.attributedText = attributedString
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)


let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)
view.addSubview(label)
```

Credits for NSBaselineOffsetAttributedName: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19445666/2494219

Comment: Thank you! I prefer to keep a UILabel so I don't have to deal with "text selection", "scrolling", etc. So your solution is great, thank you.

Comment: FYI: starting with iOS 10 this is no longer required, seems that `UILabel` has been fixed for using `NSTextAlignment.Justified`

Answer (score 4):

```
func justifyLabel(str: String) -> NSAttributedString
{
   let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
   paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
   let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: str,
                                         attributes: [
              NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
              NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset: NSNumber(value: 0)
        ])

   return attributedString
}
```

call justifyLabel() function like this...

`myLabel.attributedText = justifyLabel(myLabel.text!)`

Comment: In my case, the "NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)" was the key to make it work. Thks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this and looking for answer, and I use only this line instead of paragraphStyle or NSAttributedString.

```
self.labelDescription.textAlignment = .justified
```

Comment: Yes thanks, you're correct. As pointed by @kambala it got updated in iOS 10. When the question was posted iOS 10 was not out yet though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use UITextView for your problem.

```
bottleDescriptionTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: widthMargin, y: bottleDescriptionTextView.frame.maxY + heightMargin, width: self.view.frame.width - (2 * widthMargin), height: heightBottleDescription - (2 * heightMargin)))
bottleDescriptionTextView.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16)
bottleDescriptionTextView.text = bottleDescriptionString
bottleDescriptionTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried and it works some how but I prefer to use @Devran solution so I can keep a UILabel which is what I would like for this implementation (at least for now, but I keep your answer in mind!)

Comment: You should't use a `UITextView` in place of a `UILabel` with justified text.

Answer (score -1):

Objective-C, the perfect update solution is to used `NSMutableParagraphStyle` test on xCode 7 and iOS 9

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;      //justified text
        paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 1.0;
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: YourString attributes: attributes];
        YourLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```